# vbscript regular expression, replace between two string

Tags: regex, vbscript, asp-classic

I have this xml:

```
<doc>
<ContactPrimaryEmail></ContactPrimaryEmail>
<ContactAlternateEmail></ContactAlternateEmail> 
<ContactPrimaryMobile>+00xxxxxx</ContactPrimaryMobile>
<ContactAlternateMobile></ContactAlternateMobile> 
</doc>
```

I want to apply a regular expression in **VBScript** to replace the **content** "*+00xxxxxx*" of the attribute **ContactPrimaryMobile**, simply change the number:

```
<ContactPrimaryMobile>+00xxxxxx</ContactPrimaryMobile>
```

I am new to vbscripting and my skills in creating the objects and applying the pattern are limited, so please can you help me converting this regex to use it in VBScript:

```
(?<=\<ContactPrimaryMobile\>)(.*)(?=\<\/ContactPrimaryMobile)
```

UPDATE
I get this:

> Object doesn't support this property or method: 'Submatches'

when executing:

```
Dim oRE, oMatches
Set oRE = New RegExp
oRE.Pattern = "<ContactPrimaryMobile>(.*?)</ContactPrimaryMobile>"
oRE.Global = True
Set oMatches = oRE.Execute("<doc><ContactPrimaryEmail></ContactPrimaryEmail><ContactAlternateEmail></ContactAlternateEmail><ContactPrimaryMobile>+00xxxxxx</ContactPrimaryMobile><ContactAlternateMobile></ContactAlternateMobile></doc>")
Wscript.Echo oMatches.Submatches(0)
```

Comment: Use `<ContactPrimaryMobile>(.*?)</ContactPrimaryMobile>` and grab `match.Submatches(0)` value. Show your code if you need more concrete help.

Comment: I get this 
Object doesn't support this property or method: 'Submatches'
when executing:

Dim oRE, oMatches
Set oRE = New RegExp
oRE.Pattern = "<ContactPrimaryMobile>(.*?)</ContactPrimaryMobile>"
oRE.Global = True
Set oMatches = oRE.Execute("<doc><ContactPrimaryEmail></ContactPrimaryEmail><ContactAlternateEmail></ContactAlternateEmail><ContactPrimaryMobile>+00xxxxxx</ContactPrimaryMobile><ContactAlternateMobile></ContactAlternateMobile></doc>")
Wscript.Echo oMatches.Submatches(0)

Any further help?

Comment: Please add that to the question body. Why are you trying to get Submatches on a match collection? Access the first item. `Wscript.Echo oMatches(0).Submatches(0)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply!

Comment: No just one, but what I actually need is to replace the number in the xml with a new one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, VBScript regex does not support lookbehinds, you need to *capture* the part in between the two strings.

Next, you need to obtain the *submatch* by accessing the match object after you `.Execute` the regex match, and get its `.Submatches(0)`:

```
Dim oRE, oMatches, objMatch
oRE.Pattern = "<ContactPrimaryMobile>(.*?)</ContactPrimaryMobile>"
```

and then

```
Set oMatches = oRE.Execute(s)
For Each objMatch In oMatches
  Wscript.Echo objMatch.Submatches(0)
Next
```

To replace, use the appropriate groupings and method:

```
oRE.Pattern = "(<ContactPrimaryMobile>).*?(</ContactPrimaryMobile>)"
' and then
s = oRE.Replace(s,"$1SOME_NEW_VALUE$2")
```

Comment: Nice, I get it! Now, how can I update the number in the string?

Answer (score 2):

I know you explicitly said [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) and you have your answer but an alternative approach to getting the same end goal is to use an XML parser instead.

```vb
option explicit

dim xmldoc
set xmldoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument")
xmldoc.load "doc.xml"
dim primaryMobileNode
set primaryMobileNode = xmldoc.selectSingleNode("/doc/ContactPrimaryMobile")
primaryMobileNode.text = "new value"
xmldoc.save "changed-doc.xml"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. good point, I thought it too. But I don't read the xml from from a file. It is coming from a database as an adodb object. I thought it would be faster to use regex